# Symfony3 can't create translated routes with router in service

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-3.2, php-7.1

I'm trying to build a language switcher into my main navigation, which is created by the [KNPMenuBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle). Translations are done with the [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle). Both work fine.

I want to create a language switcher with my menu builder, but the generation of the correct routes gives me some headaches.

This is my service:

```
class MenuService
{
    private $factory;
    private $translator;
    private $router;

    public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory, Translator $translator, Router $router)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function createMainMenu(RequestStack $requestStack, array $languages)
    {
        // Language Switcher - $languages === ['en', 'de']
        $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        $routeName = $request->get('_route');

        $menu->addChild('menu.language', array(
            'uri' => '#',
            'label' => '<i class=\'fa fa-flag-checkered\'></i> '.$this->translator->trans('menu.language.main'),
            'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
        ))
            ->setAttribute('class', 'dropdown singleDrop')
            ->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left')
        ;

        foreach ($languages as $language)
        {
            $menu->getChild('menu.language')->addChild('menu.language.'.$language, array(
                'route' => $this->router->generate($routeName, array_merge($request->get('_route_params'), ['_locale' => $language]))
            ));
        }
    }
```

And this is my service definition

```
menu_builder:
    class: AppBundle\DependencyInjection\MenuService
    arguments: ['@knp_menu.factory', '@translator.default', '@jms_i18n_routing.router']

menu.main:
    class: Knp\Menu\MenuItem
    factory: ['@menu_builder', createMainMenu]
    arguments: ['@request_stack', '%locales%']
    scope: request
    tags:
      - { name: knp_menu.menu, alias: main }
```

If I inject the Router provided by the JMSTranslationBundle, I receive the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "/en/" as such route
>   does not exist.").

If I'm using the default router of symfony I'm getting this error message:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "homepage" as such
>   route does not exist.").

When I debug the router on the console, this is the output:

```
  en__RG__homepage                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /en/                                                 
  de__RG__homepage                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /de/
```

Which router must be used to get the routing to work?

Comment: where does `$routeName` in `'route' => $this->router->generate($routeName, array_merge($request->get('_route_params'), ['_locale' => $language]))` comes from?

Comment: @lordrhodos I've edited my question, I've forgot that part, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I think you must use : JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router, see https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/I18nRouter.php Hope this helps !

Comment: @MathieuDormeval thank you for your reply. Truly, I must use the Router from the JMS Routing Bundle, but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my mistake with the usage of those two bundles.

The `JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router::generate()` function will return the **absolute path** for the route given to the function.

So the following happens:

```
$absolutePath = $this->router->generate('homepage', array_merge($request->get('_route_params'), ['_locale' => $language]));
dump($absolutePath); // Will return "/de/" or "/en" in my case
```

So, taken that into account, my generation of the routes with the parameter `route` will obviously fail, because the function doesn't return the `route` but the `absolute path`.

Given that, this works:

```
foreach ($languages as $language)
{
    $menu->getChild('menu.language')->addChild('menu.language.'.$language, array(
        'uri' => $this->router->generate($routeName, array_merge($request->get('_route_params'), ['_locale' => $language]))
    ));
}
```

If I change the `route` to `uri` my code works correctly.